# ACCESS - Crosstab query - nearest match

Tags: mysql, ms-access, crosstab

Problem is that database is missing some values and I need to lookup them in crosstab query with the nearest.

The table which I crosstab seems like this:

[image: Source data]

It has missing values for competitor prices - For item 111 i don't have price for 3rd week for first competitor and for 2nd week for 2nd competitor. For item 222 i miss 2nd week price for 1st competitor and 1,3 week for 2nd competitor. I want to use the nearest week price in my output data.

Output (for price index calculation) must look like this (competitor prices in columns in order to make calculations further in pivot table in excel):

[image]

The question is how to "lookup" nearest week competitor prices, i marked missing prices in orange.

I hope the problem is clear, in case of any questions - please ask, I'll try to clarify everything!
Great thanks in advance!

Upd.
I try to do it in the following way (with subquery):

```
     SELECT m_week, item_code, my_price, (SELECT TOP 1 com_price
     FROM MyTable AS T
     WHERE T.item_code = MyTable.item_code
     AND T.m_week <= MyTable.m_week
     AND competotor_id = 1
     ORDER BY T.m_week) AS Comp1_price, (SELECT TOP 1 com_price
     FROM MyTable AS T
     WHERE T.item_code = MyTable.item_code
     AND T.m_week <= MyTable.m_week
     AND competotor_id = 2
     ORDER BY T.m_week) AS Comp2_price
     ... the same for each competitor
     FROM MyTable
```

It works.. but very slow and i need to copy/paste for each competitor. The next thing - i want to search prices not only down, but also up (along the weeks)

Answer (score 0):

You could base your crosstab on a query that uses subqueries:

`SELECT p.competitor_id, p.m_week, p.item_code,  p.com_price, p.my_price,

 nz(p.com_price, 
(Select top 1 week_price FROM
  (
    SELECT m_week, item_code, Max(com_price) AS week_price
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE com_price Is Not Null
    GROUP BY m_week, item_code
  ) as WeekPrices 
WHERE  [item_code]=p.item_code and m_week < p.m_week
ORDER BY m_week desc))  as com_price_calc
FROM YourTable AS p;`

- This results in the table, with a com_price_calc column with the null data filled in.
- I have aliased YourTable as p - for parent
- The nz() function is for access only, you can replace it with ifnull()
  if your using mysql
- The inner subquery shows the weekly price for
  each m_week - item_code combination, where it is not null.
- The outer subquery filters for parent item_code and a previous week and since it uses 'ORDER BY m_week desc', top 1 will return the previous weeks
  value.

Comment: Greetings and thank you! But as i read your answer i realized that i made mistake in problem description. I actually don't have rows with missing prices and i think it complicates initial question.

Comment: Maybe i can somehow add nz() function into crosstab query.  Now it seems like this  `TRANSFORM Avg(p.com_price)  SELECT p.m_week, p.item_code,  p.my_price  FROM MyTable as p GROUP BY p.m_week, p.item_code,  p.my_price  PIVOT p.competitor_id`